# How to adjust randomization level javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm developing 8 puzzle game using javascript, I shuffle the tiles by shuffling the puzzle tiles array

[image]

```
var shuffleArray = (array) => {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
};
```

I want to give the user the option to choose difficulty: easy, medium, hard,
How can I implment this?

## Update:

I will explain a little bit my implmentation. (this is typescript)

The puzzle array is an array of class `PuzzleNode`

```
export class PuzzleNode {
  goal: Node;
  current: Node;
}
```

When I shuffle I don't touch the puzzleArray but I shuffle the `current` property like so

```
shuffle() {
   this.shuffledNodes = shuffleArray(this.shuffledNodes);
   for (let i = 0; i < this.shuffledNodes.length; i++) {
     this.puzzleNodes[i].current = this.shuffledNodes[i];
   }
   /** Keep shuffling until getting a solvable puzzle */
   if (!this.isSolvable()) {
     this.shuffle();
    }
}
```

This way I can reach any node using the index, because the index doesn't change even after shuffling, for instance the blank tile is always `puzzleNodes[8]`

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is make the game logic actually start with the completed board, and then move the pieces randomly, just as a player playing the game.  For a low difficulty level you may only want to make 10 moves, but for a higher difficulty level you could make 50.

Comment: This depend on what you meant by hard. does `hard` mean increasing the number of tiles??

Comment: Yeah shuffling the board like that is a good way of ensuring it's solvable

Comment: @Brian I already have a function to check if it solvable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to vary the difficulty would be to reduce or increase the number of moves required to solve it.

I think the best way to go about this is to implement the shuffling algorithm as a reverse of the way it will be solved: while shuffling, only pick legal moves (move a piece into an adjacent gap), and repeat this randomly for a certain number of moves until it's sufficiently shuffled.

For easy mode, only do about 5 moves.  For hard, do 30 moves.  A puzzle that requires 5 moves to solve will be a lot easier.

Comment: I think that I need a search algorithm that figures out how to solve it like A* search algorithm maybe! it also counts the amount of steps needed

Comment: If he actually did that he would end up with a problem which might have a shorter solution.

Comment: Essentially the more you shuffle it the more likely that it is that a shorter solution( than moves shuffling) is available because reversing the method you're using to shuffle it isn't necessarily the most efficient way to solving it. Think if your shuffle say moves a piece then moves it back again, or moves the pieces in a circle - you don't need a move to correct those pieces. Calculating average piece displacement might be a more accurate way of determining difficulty if restricted to a 3x3 grid you could have difficulties based on displacement thresholds and shuffle till they're satisfied.

Comment: I can perform the A* search and get the steps count needed to solve the puzzle, check if it's within the difficulty level range, if not shuffle again.. but It might be not the best solution @Brian

Comment: You could always check it every 10 or so pieces shuffled to reduce the overheads. @thomasrutter is right - moves required is probably the biggest factor in difficulty without increasing grid size. Displacement thresholds would probably be less computationally intense but also less accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to make it more difficult a few ideas:

- Increasing the piece count so that it's a 4x4 or 5x5 grid or making it a non-square shape (ie stray pieces) - larger piece counts would require more work and the more a larger board is shuffled the more difficult it's likely to be.
- Obstacles like a locked tile that can't be moved
- A time limit
- A move limit - if you use @Archers suggestion for starting the game you could know a rough minimum amount of moves to solve - easy could be moves + 20 medium moves + 10 hard moves + 5.

As for implementing it you'd just do a `Math.floor(Math.random()*3)` to decide the direction of the move and assign directions to the numbers one through four

Each of the move functions would need to be able to handle an invalid move - it may be worth returning a false result if it fails so that you can ensure you actually get the amount of shuffling you want.

```
 function moveLeft(){
     // Code to move a piece left here 
 }
// ... other movement functions
function scrambleBoard(){
// Assign directions to an array so that we can easilly reference them with a random number
     var directions = 
        [moveLeft, 
         moveUp,
         moveRight,
         moveDown];

     for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        // Generate a number between 0 and 3 then call the function at that array index
        var result = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)](); 
        // We tried to make an invalid move so this iteration never happened 
        if(result === false) i--;     
     }
}
```

Why I compare result === false is you may wish for the move functions to return a new position so if the position was ever 0 it could mistakenly add extra iterations.